# Crashing issue with large amount of data in iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am working on the app in which large amount of data (e.g **30K** dictionary in array) is received through web service. 
I am using JSON kit for parsing this large amount of data. After getting response, i will store this data into plist file(because i want to run app in offline mode).

After that i am accessing this data using NSMutableArray(with **30K** dictionary). Now for further calculation i am using this array and use this loop **7- 8 times** for calculation to draw the Graph.

```
//path = path from which i access the plist

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];

//where array contains about 30K dictionaries.

for(int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {

    // some calculation formula
}
```

same loop is called 7-8 times after executing the above loop.

My app is crashing after i read the data from plist due to memory issue. Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: You do not provide enough context for your problem... Post error description when app crashes (is it doe to the low memory?), post code how you create/store that data and how you dispose of it

Comment: Yeah, you need to post the error description AND a skeletal code (at least) so that we could help you optimize your code as well.

Comment: First, at least implement the minimum `..DidReceiveMemoryWarning` methods for app delegate and view controllers, and log the fact that they were entered.

Comment: (And, of course, indicate what error messages you're getting.)

Comment: App is crashing due to memory issue. I have check the memory usage using Instruments and app is crashing due to out of memory problem.

Comment: Isn't there any error message when the app crashes?

Comment: no, there is no error message. But when i have checked with Instruments, it is showing that app is running with very large memory.

Comment: This kind of crash means you are allocating too much memory. You need a better approach. Store the records in a sqlite database but then only process 100 of them at a time. The way your code is now, you are attempting to load all the data into memory before running the loop. That is going to cause the crash due to too much memory being used at one time.

Answer (score 0):

As your issue is memory related you have to free the memory asap. I assume that you are using ARC with iOS 6.0. Try using the loop inside the @autoreleasepool and see if that makes any difference. You can also use nested @autoreleasepool if you need.

```
for(int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {
   @autoreleasepool {
       // calculation formula
    }
}
```

Old way;

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
for(int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {
       // calculation formula
}
[pool drain];
```

Comment: i am not using ARC in my app. But i thing this is because of large amount of data and 7-8 for loop with this large data.

Comment: You can use old way NSAutoreleasePool in that case. While looping put couple of NSAutoreleasePool and see if that helps.

Comment: I suggest switching to ARC if possible. It saves time and errors.

Comment: @applefreak Thanks for the reply. i think this will help to solve problem

Comment: @nielsbot but i don't know how to switch to ARC. Can you tell me how to enable ARC in non-ARC Project??

Comment: Ask another question on the ARC. It's unrelated to this question. I will reply there.